# Crystal reports related

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have seen many sites but couldn’t find the proper answer. I want content in report header but instead of keeping content in details section my requirement is to keep in the report footer. When I inserted a subreport in footer a and another in report b they are showing up on different pages.how can I make them appear on the single page? 
Thanks in advance,
RAM

Comment: If you write theory no one will be able to provide you the answer. You need to explain what you have done and where you are struck. For these type of question it would be helpful if you can explain or show the design. You are lucky question is not closed, Normally these type of questions will be closed

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you have a Report Footer that has been created with 2 sub-sections that are each printing on separate pages.  If this is the case, then you can go into Section Expert and select the top level Report Footer section (the one that contains the Report Footer A and Report Footer B sub-sections) and then check the checkbox for Keep Together.  This will ensure that all of the sub-sections within the Report Footer are printed on the same page together.

Keep in mind that things can still be pushed to a second page depending upon how you design the report.  But as long as the content will all fit on one page the Keep Together property should get the job done well enough.